# Making a fake screensaver in PPT using VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm trying to mimic a screensaver on PowerPoint that will return to my first slide after X amount of seconds of inactivity.

The PowerPoint presentation is all just completely image based and every click will transition through the slides, so it doesn't have to be sophisticated at all, just that at the start of each slide it counts down 5 seconds, then returns to slide 1 (which is my fake screensaver page).

I've already got something working in a basic format, it takes you to the first page after 5 seconds, but the timer doesn't restart once you go to a new slide, once it starts counting down, regardless of if you move to the next slide after 3 seconds, you don't get another 5 second countdown, it just finishes the remaining 2 seconds and redirects you.

VBA is definitely not my primary language, I'm just piecing this together with what I can find, but my current code is below

```
Sub Auto_NextSlide(Index As Long)

Dim Delay, Start

If Index > 1 Then
    Delay = 5
    Start = Timer
    Do While Timer < Start + Delay
        DoEvents
    Loop

    SlideShowWindows(1).View.GotoSlide (SlideShowWindows(1).Presentation.Slides(1).SlideIndex)
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: you need to reset `Start` at page 1 otherwise it isn't set when going to the screen saver.  I think

Comment: @Nathan_Sav It's not really had any effect, I think I need a way of resetting the timer each time, it seems as though it's just doing that while loop regardless. Is that the correct kinda way you'd write a countdown though? Like I say, I'm not a VBA man

Answer (score 0):

Try maybe something like below (using class events)

```
' AppEvents class module
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents App As Application

Const Delay As Integer = 5

Dim Start
Dim actualSlide As Integer


Private Sub App_SlideShowNextSlide(ByVal Wn As SlideShowWindow)
    With Wn.Presentation.SlideShowWindow
        Start = Timer
        actualSlide = .View.Slide.SlideIndex
        If actualSlide > 1 Then
            Do While Timer < Start + Delay
                DoEvents
                If .View.Slide.SlideIndex <> actualSlide Then
                    Start = Timer
                    actualSlide = .View.Slide.SlideIndex
                End If
            Loop
            .View.GotoSlide (.Presentation.Slides(1).SlideIndex)
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Module code

```
' Module 1
Option Explicit

Public pApp As AppEvents

Sub GetAppClass()
    Set pApp = New AppEvents
    Set pApp.App = Application
    ActivePresentation.SlideShowSettings.Run
End Sub
```